# Why value of a=0 after entering atleast one time invalid integer

Tags: c#, tryparse

I am trying to use `TryParse` method in c#.
I am creating a program which takes input from user and if it is integer then return to a variable. Program works fine when input is valid integer but once I enter the invalid number like `12sd` it returns `a=0`. Where is the mistake.

```
public int checkValidNumber()
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    int a = 0;
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    if(!int.TryParse(str, out a))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
      obj.checkValidNumber();
    }
    return a;
}
```

Calling in Main using

```
Program obj = new Program();
int a = obj.checkValidNumber();
```

where as Program is a Class, Consider a console application please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `obj.checkValidNumber();` with:

```
a = obj.checkValidNumber();
//Or
return obj.checkValidNumber();
```

In addition `checkValidNumber` is a member function of `Program`, there is no reason to create a new instance of `Program` in each call

```
public int checkValidNumber()
{
    int a=0;
    if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
      return checkValidNumber();
    }
    return a;
}
```

But probably better to use a while loop for this, rather than a recursive call:

```
public int checkValidNumber()
{
    int a=0;
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
    }
    return a;
}
```

*If using C#7.0 see the [new usage of an out variable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) for the `TryParse`*

Comment: Thanks for guidance. You suggestion not to use object in method and use of while loop both helped.

Comment: @Arunkumar - Glad it helped :) Also see the c# 7.0 if that is what you are using